# Commit isn't showing up on github?

Tags: git, github, console

I added the files I wanted:

```
git add ....
```

I then ran git commit. When I call:

> git commit

I get:

> On branch refactor
>   nothing to commit, working directory clean

I am in branch refactor. However when I check on github the last activity was a day ago and none of the code is updated? I've previously used the UI github app this is my first time doing this through the console. What's going wrong?

If there is nothing to commit, why is it not showing up?

Comment: Nothing to commit means that there are no changes done to the original files. you have to git push after you commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to 'push'. The commit now exists only in your local copy.

Sourcetree is an app that will make your life easier, I personally like using it because you can easily detect issues like this: sourcetree will show you that your local copy is not in sync with 'remote' and will offer you to push/pull respectfully.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to commit means that there are no changes done to the original files. you have to git push after you commit.